# Opencart Filter Pagination Issue

Tags: opencart

I have assigned a filter(default) in my opencart(1.5.6.4) store. I have 16 product displaying at single page. So whenever I select a filter module  & refine search it worked ok for first 16 product but when page 2 is clicked it shows all product.Suppose I have selected 27 product in filter..it shows 1to 16 product of 27 but when I clicked page 2 its showing 17 to 32 of 368 products.

Comment: 'I have assigned a filter in my opencart store.' - Update your question with some code.

Comment: I haven't write any custom code or edit..i have just assigned default opencart filter for my store

Comment: So you didn't make any change in code and you've this issue in your opencart fresh installation, right?